# export multiple results from a single store procedure into multiple tabs of an excel sheet using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a stored procedure which returns multiple result set(say, 5 results). All these 5 results are stored in 5 different temporary tables.
Now, I need to save these 5 result sets from these 5 temporary tables into 5 different tabs of a single excel file using SSIS.
I have placed DFT and excel destination, and selected the stored procedure that needs to be run.
But I don't know how to set the path so as to save all these 5 result sets in a single excel file into 5 tabs.

can someone help me in this as I'm a beginner of SSIS.

Comment: I'm a touch confused. The Stored procedure executes and when it's done executing, it has created and ?filled temporary tables that you hope to use?

Comment: @billinkc -- The stored procedure created 5 temporary tables and filled data in those tables. Now, how will I fetch these result and save it in 5 tabs of an excel? Is it possible, since we are using temporary tables? I just wanted to avoid creating multiple views and hence went for temporary table creation.

Comment: So when the stored procedure completes, those _temporary_ tables go away with the connection. Unless you're talking about global temporary tables which you can then use as a source in SSIS but it's a bit fiddly as you'll need to delay validation and retain connection and use an Execute sql task in a precursor to the DFT and then any time you edit the package, validation flips out... It's a mess